# Creating and Updating a CFN stack through Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a self-assuming IAM role through Terraform. with CFN I usually create the role in one run and update the self-assuming part in the next run. I am trying to implement this in a single step on Terraform.

Like I have two CFN templates what I want is to build a logic that runs the first template and then the second one.

I can't find a CFN update module in the registry, any idea?

Not sure if this has been asked before

I tried running it as two separate resources but the conflict. I would really appreciate it if someone could share any conditional logic that can help me do this in one step.

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "uc_cloud_resources-cfn" {
      name          = "${local.prefix}-${lower(var.BusinessUnit)}-${lower(var.Department)}-${lower(var.Environment)}-sc-stack"
      capabilities  = ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM","CAPABILITY_IAM"]
      parameters    = {
                RoleName     =      "${var.RoleName}"
                BucketName   =      "${var.BucketName}"
                BusinessUnit =      "${var.BusinessUnit}"
                Environment  =      "${var.Environment}"
                Department   =      "${var.Department}"
      }
    #template_body   = file("/path/to/deployment/template1.json")
    template_body   = file("/path/to/deployment/template2.json")
}
```

For now, this code is running but I manually run it twice editing the template.

I tried this too

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "uc_cloud_resources-cfn" {
  name          = "${local.prefix}-${lower(var.BusinessUnit)}-${lower(var.Department)}-${lower(var.Environment)}-sc-stack"
  capabilities  = ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM","CAPABILITY_IAM"]
  parameters    = {
    RoleName     =      "${var.RoleName}"
    BucketName   =      "${var.BucketName}"
    BusinessUnit =      "${var.BusinessUnit}"
    Environment  =      "${var.Environment}"
    Department   =      "${var.Department}"
  }
  template_body   = file("/path/to/template1.json")
}

resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "uc_cloud_resources-cfn_update" {
  name = "${local.prefix}-${lower(var.BusinessUnit)}-${lower(var.Department)}-${lower(var.Environment)}-sc-stack"
  capabilities  = ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM","CAPABILITY_IAM"]
  depends_on      =   [ aws_cloudformation_stack.uc_cloud_resources-cfn ]
  parameters      =   {
    RoleName        =      "${var.RoleName}"
    BucketName      =      "${var.BucketName}"
    BusinessUnit    =      "${var.BusinessUnit}"
    Environment     =      "${var.Environment}"
    Department      =      "${var.Department}"
  }
  template_body   = file("/path/to/template2.json")
}
```

This one gives an error that stack exists

Comment: Please add any code you have tried to the question.

Comment: Added the part running in the post. New to Terraform so not that good in setting up conditional logic here

Comment: Is there anything in the first template that is used by the second template? What is the error you are getting? I'm guessing it's related to the stack name because you don't change it across applies.

Comment: This is not getting any error. Everything works perfectly. What I want to do is create the stack and then update it in the same terraform run. I want to build the logic for it

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Let me update the post again

Comment: have a look at it now

Comment: Well, you mentioned a conflict, then said it works fine. I'm no longer sure which is true.

Comment: you want to update the same stack in the same run? If so, that is not possible. Also, the conflict you are getting is because the name is the same in both cases. If you can have two stacks, then I would suggest changing the name of the stack.

Comment: Oh I just wanted to create a self assuming role in one go I'll figure out some way to workaround